# Is there a way to make CTabItem not accessible by the user?

Tags: java, swt, ctabitem

I am using CTabItem to make selectable interfaces. I need one tab to be unavailable for the user until some other events, but I cannot figure out a way (as I don't see such methods in the documentation. Any hints on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to disable an existing `CTabItem`.

You can add additional tabs to the tab folder after it has been created and shown so you could delay adding the tab until the event happens.

Comment: Alternatively, you can disable or hide the contents of the tab.

Comment: What do you mean by disable to content of the tab?Could you please elaborate. I need to make inactive only the CTabItem, not the CTabFolder.